# Invariant event defined in terms of stationary stochastic sequence

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationarity, ergodic

In "Almost Sure Convergence" by Stout, there is indicated that the concept of invariant event (and further, the concept of ergodicity) can be defined in terms of given stationary stochastic sequence $\{X_n,n\geq1\}$ (with no reference to the concept of measure-preserving transformation) as:
$$
A=\{\omega\in\Omega\,|\,(X_k(\omega),\,X_{k+1}(\omega),\,\dots)\in B\}\in\sigma(X_n,\,n\geq1),\quad \forall k\geq1.
$$
Here, $\Omega$ is a set of possible states of the world, $\omega$ its generic element,  $B$ is some set belonging to sigma-algebra generated by a family of cylinder sets, and $\sigma(X_n,\,n\geq1)$ is sigma-algebra generated by the the process.

So, stochastic process go through set $B$ if and only if, its shifted version starting from observation $k\geq2$, goes through set $B$. What is a practical meaning of above definition?

References:
Stout, William F. (1974), Almost Sure Convergence.

Comment: This notation is inconsistent with mathematical conventions: if $B$ is a set of "values," then the *infinite vector* $(X_k(\omega),X_{k+1}(\omega),\ldots)$ cannot be an element of $B.$  Please explain or correct your notation.

Comment: @whuber I meant $B$ is some set of values of the **whole process**; in other words, element of sigma-field generated by cylinder sets.

Comment: That's still inconsistent with your notation, because all cylinder sets will have elements that are infinite vectors corresponding to the values of $X_1, X_2,\ldots.$

Comment: @whuber I think that I confused a few objects. I made an edit, defining $B$ as some element of cylinder sigma-algebra.